# Magento Google tag manager manually

Tags: magento, google-tag-manager

I have a website which is running on Magento. There i'd like to add a code inside the body tag of each page. Where can i find this on my website? Is this a single file or do i have to do this on every page.

Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it in Magento backend:

1. Log into Magento backend;
2. Navigate to System→Configuration, under ‘General’ open ‘Design’,
   scroll down and click to extend the Html Head section;
3. Paste the GTM Code into the field next to Miscellaneous Scripts;